# What is the correct way to return a matrix result in this python function?

Tags: python, debugging, matrix, syntax-error, inverse

Here is the definition of my Matrix class

```
class Matrix(object):

    # Constructor
    def __init__(self, grid):
        self.g = grid
        self.h = len(grid)
        self.w = len(grid[0])

    def inverse(self):
        """
        Calculates the inverse of a 1x1 or 2x2 Matrix.
        """
        if not self.is_square():
            raise(ValueError, "Non-square Matrix does not have an inverse.")
        if self.h > 2:
            raise(NotImplementedError, "inversion not implemented for matrices larger than 2x2.")

        # TODO - your code here

        invert = zeroes(1,1)
        if self.h == 1:
            invert[0][0]=(1/self.g[0][0])

        elif self.h == 2:
            # Calculate the inverse of the square 1x1 or 2x2 matrix.
            a = self.g[0][0]
            b = self.g[0][1]
            c = self.g[1][0]
            d = self.g[1][1]

            factor = 1 / (a * d - b * c)

            invert = [[d, -b],[-c, a]]

            for i in range(self.h):
                for j in range(self.w):
                    invert[i][j] = factor * invert[i][j]  

        return Matrix(invert)
```

The error I receive is TypeError: object of type "Matrix" has no len(). The result however needs to an inverse of a matrix size 1x1.

Comment: You might consider tagging the language

Comment: Thanks Christian for the tip. Just added the tag. Its in python.

Comment: You should post the exact error you are getting, including the line where it happens and the traceback. Also, post the code needed to reproduce the error. This code only defines a class and does nothing with it.